# JAXWS and sessions

Tags: java, web-services, soap, session, jax-ws

I'm fairly new to writing web services.  I'm working on a SOAP service using JAXWS.  I'd like to be able to have users log-in and in my service know which user is issuing a command.  In other words, have some session handling.

One way I've seen to do this is to use cookies and access the HTTP layer from my web service.  However, this puts a dependency on using HTTP as the transport layer (I'm aware HTTP is almost always the transport layer but I'm a purist).

Is there a better approach which keeps the service layer unaware of the transport layer?  Is there some way I can accomplish this with servlet filters?  I'd like the answer to be as framework agnostic as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm working on a SOAP service using JAXWS. I'd like to be able to have users log-in and in my service know which user is issuing a command. In other words, have some session handling.

Conventional Web services are stateless in nature, there is no *session handling* in web services (which has by the say nothing to do with identifying the caller).

If you want to require your users to be authenticated to call a service, the traditional approach is to:

1. Expose an "authentication" web service (passing user credentials) that returns an authentication token.
2. Have the users call this authentication first.
3. Have the users pass the token in a custom header on subsequent calls of "business" web services.

On the server side:

1. Reject any call that doesn't contain a valid token.
2. Invalidate tokens after some time of inactivity

You can implement a custom solution for this approach (this is a highly interoperable solution). Or you can use [WS-Security](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4gmi9EiSO7kJ:docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0.pdf&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=3&gl=us&client=firefox-a)/[UsernameTokens](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16782/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf) that provides something similar out of the box. WS-Security is a standard (Metro implements it), it isn't "framework" specific.

Comment: Outstanding answer.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, servlet filters can provide the basis of solution. Use a filter to store the current session details (e.g. the session context Map) in a threadLocal storage. This is implemented as your application class, so is transport agnostic. Your service simply uses a static method to fetch the current context, unaware of where it came from.

E.g.

```
class ServiceSessionContext
{
    static ThreadLocal<Map> local = new ThreadLocal<Map>();

    // context set by the transport layer, e.g. servlet filter
    static public void setContext(Map map)
    {
        local.put(map);
    }

    // called when request is complete
    static public void clearContext()
    {
        local.put(null);
    }

    // context fetched by the service
    static public Map getContext()
    {
        return local.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I can use this pattern to pass the token mentioned above into my service layer.